# Move irregular shape in c#

Tags: c#, graphics

I am currently working with c# PictureBox and I have made handsfree drawing in picture box which are irregular shapes and horizontal lines. how to move the selected irregular shape with the mouse move.

```
public class IrregularShape
{
    public Color ShapeColor { get; set; }
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }
    public List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
}
```

I have the selected shape in mouse down with start,end and a list of points of that shape.

Comment: What code have you tried with respect to moving it?

Comment: Draw in the pBox.Paint triggered from the pBox.MouseMove! Remember the position and store it so you can translateTransform the graphics next time. (Or transpose the points) Not sure what Start and End are; the points list should have a first() and last()..

Comment: Glad to have finally found this.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to have finally found this. 
In mouse down write this code:

```
                    isdraggingshape = true;
                    if (selectedshape != null)
                        {
                           OffsetX = selectedshape.Start.X - e.Location.X;
                           OffsetY = selectedshape.Start.Y - e.Location.Y;

                        }
```

in mouse move:

```
          if (isdraggingshape == true)
                {
                    if (OffsetX != null && OffsetY != null)
                    {
                        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                        { int new_x1 = e.X + OffsetX;
                            int new_y1 = e.Y + OffsetY;
                            int dx = new_x1 - selectedshape.Start.X;
                            int dy = new_y1 - selectedshape.Start.Y;
                            if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) return;

                            // Move the shape
                            for (int i = 0; i < selectedshape.points.Count; i++)
                            {
                                selectedshape.points[i] = new Point(selectedshape.points[i].X + dx,selectedshape.points[i].Y + dy);
                            }

                            // Redraw.
                            ImagepictureBox.Invalidate();
                        }
```